# Equilibrium points non-linear system of differential equations with parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I am studying a paper about populations dynamics (for the interested reader:https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10955-014-0989-8). Eventually we have a system of differential equations where, in the paper, they provide equilibrium points. I tried to work out how they obtained these points but I just cannot find the right way. The system is
$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = -\rho x (1-(x+y)) + (q-x)(x+y)$$
$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = -y(1-(x+y)) + \rho (1-q-y)(x+y)$$
With given equilibrium points:
\begin{align}
&(0,0) \\
&(q,1-q) \\
&\left(\frac{q(1+\rho)-\rho}{(1+\rho)(1-\rho)}, \rho \frac{q(1+\rho)-\rho}{(1+\rho)(1-\rho)} \right)
\end{align}
I am interested in the third equilibrium point.

I tried substitution but that became very hard to solve. Furthermore I tried to define a variable $z=x+y$ such that also $\dot{z} = \dot{x} + \dot{y}$. Now if $\dot{x} = 0$ and $\dot{y}=0$ we also have that $\dot{z} = 0$. I worked on $\dot{z}$ until the following expression:
$$\dot{z} =x(1-\rho)(1-z) + z(1-z) + q(1+\rho)z - z^2 + y(1-\rho)z+\rho z $$
I also tried to solve this one but still could not figure it out.
Since the third equilibrium point is a quite nice expression I think maybe overlooked something. Maybe there is a simple way to solve this?